# Can weekly newsletter be sorted by tags?

Tags: support, newsletter

I saw the right hand corner "LOVE this site?" advertisement. Then I click on the sample newsletter. It's just a whole page of questions (possibly irrelevant/makes no interest the way it looks).

Would the following be more helpful?

- letting users choose what they want in their newsletter
- or else, moderators may choose those which needs more input or those Q&A with quality which benefits larger group of users

I am not sure the motivation behind the newsletter - for now, it doesn't look that appealing.

Any comments?

Comment: I haven't subscribed to the newsletter (yet), but going by your description, yeah... I'd be more inclined to subscribe if it means getting questions from  only the tags I've marked as "favorite" + the week's HNQs (irrespective of the tag). O:)

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing that you or I can do about the official newsletter.

The inability to customise the newsletter has been discussed a few times; for a question that is similar to what you are asking, see: [Can newsletters take into account a user's favorite tags on that site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110902/can-newsletters-take-into-account-a-users-favorite-tags-on-that-site)

A cursory search on meta.SE led me to this, which you may be interested in: [StackLetter - Personalized newsletter for Stack Exchange](https://www.stackletter.com) I haven't used it before, so I don't know what features it has, though.

Comment: I would add that the newsletter is quite useful for other sites. That is, if I spend most of my SE-allocated time on Chem, then I do find the summaries of Math, Physics, and English to be interesting.

Comment: Fair enough, I will tweak the wording a little.. I am a one-site user, so this has never occurred to me ;)

Comment: I rather enjoyed the rewording. Something about it screams elegant and fashionable. Though your second claim isn't quite true... Didn't I once read an orthocresol™ pH calculation of a solution for making pretzels?

Comment: *furiously pings cooking.SE moderators to migrate the question to chemistry*

Comment: If thou doth protest too much, methinks I might consider a bounty with the association bonus.

Comment: I'm not sure about that - it might be viewed with suspicion.

Answer (score 3):

The newsletter for reasons mentioned by orthocresol really is only useful, if you follow the site irregularly.

If you don't mind getting lots - and that might be a crazy amount, depending on the tag - then you can subscribe to newsletters for tags. That might be a great idea if you are a specialist in [rare-earth-elements](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rare-earth-elements) (8 questions in 2017 until now) and don't want to miss one of the rare (pun intended) occasions. It might be a medium good idea if you want to follow [aromatic-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aromatic-compounds) (265 questions in 2017 until now); it might be a terrible idea to follow [organic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-chemistry) (2500+ excluding already deleted in 2017).

You can easily subscribe to a tag, going to the tag-page. If you hover over it, it opens a pop-up, were there are links to subscribe and for rss. (Theoretically that should work on any page, except in the favourite tag section.) You need to confirm the e-mail subscription.

[image: hover text to subscribe]

Alternatively, you can create filters at https://stackexchange.com/filters and subscribe to these ones.

[image: a sample filter]

It is a bit tedious to get going, but depending on what you want to watch, it might be worth looking into.